# How I can bind keys for selecting language directly in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout

I like to change keyboard bindings directly to language that I want to use
I use the following keyboard bindings to change keyboard layout in Windows:

left alt+left shift+1 for English
left alt+left shift+2 for Russian
left alt+left shift+3 for Ukrainian

How I can configure Ubuntu 13.04 for doing the same? I've found how to change keyboard layout choosing languages in order (Alt+shift, for example), but like to use approach that I've described already

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to configure custom shortcuts in Unity (and google tells me, that the most appropriate way is to use [gsettings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal) or [xbindkeys](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=79560)).

As a GNOME 3 user, I go to
`All settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab -> Custom`
and hit the "+" button.

After you managed to create custom shortcuts, you can assign Ctrl-Alt-1 to `setxkbmap ua`, Ctrl-Alt-2 to `setxkbmap ru`, Ctrl-Alt-3 to `setxkbmap us`.

*There is a bug in it*, at least for me. When I switch to ru or ua, the global shortcuts, like Ctrl-W or Ctrl-T stop working, like, GNOME does not understand Ctrl-Ц and Ctrl-Е. Also, my usual layout-switching button stops working.

Comment: Try a different keyboard shortcut other than Ctrl-Alt-1, Ctrl-Alt-2 and Ctrl-Alt-3 and maybe it will work. For what seems to me to be no apparent reason Unity doesn't like it if you use some keyboard combinations as keyboard shortcuts.